Upgrading to .NET8 seems to have changed the entire structure of my project
Context:
I have a C# project that contains a platform layer consisting of 9 DLLs, several of which reference each other. Then I have a group of 20 command-line programs that use the platform layer in various ways, but don't try to talk to each other. In other words, they are independent silos. All of these are individual sub-projects of a single solution, implemented in Visual Studio, running in VStudio 2022, based on .NET 4.8. Everything was working perfectly and building without errors.
As part of the solution structure, I have two directories, Debug and Release, placed immediately under the top-level solution directory. All build output is directed into the appropriate one of the directories, so all cross-references are easily resolved, and creating a release package is a simple matter.
I decided to upgrade the whole solution to .NET 8, and used the Upgrade feature in the solution. I had to do it sub-project at a time, as trying to do the entire solution at once seemed to kill VStudio. After upgrading each sub-project, I had to reset the Build Output location in it back to my Debug directory.
However, now when I rebuild the solution, I am getting myriad errors of the form "Metadata file ...dll could not be found", referring to directories that are subordinate to my Debug directory and that do not exist, nor did I specify them. These errors are followed by about a thousand errors telling me about missing type names that are of course defined in the platform DLLs.
Could someone explain to me what changes .NET is forcing, how to adapt my project, and why Microsoft, once again, can't leave well enough alone when it comes to the tools that developers actually require? I have upgraded this project through various flavours of .NET in the past, as the platform code has existed for at least half a dozen years. It was always simply a case of installing the new SDK and changing the target platform in the Properties. Now, it seems that the entire solution needs to be restructured in a way that may not even work properly.
Any help gratefully accepted.
Norm

Does your platform layer include circular references? You might need to resolve that. Otherwise I'd leave the output folders alone. It's hard to give any specific answer without more specific details. I would recommend you create a new solution in a temp folder with a number of empty projects, one per subfolder, just to get a feel for how .net 8 would normally structure things. Which you can compare to your current solution. Since .net core attempted to simplify how projects are defined, which ended up being used since .net 5.

Also check the document:
Modernize after upgrading to .NET from .NET Framework
Some libraries aren't. Many .NET Framework-specific libraries have been ported to .NET or .NET Standard, and are hosted on NuGet. If you find a missing reference in your project, search NuGet.
If possible, please re-add the dependencies manually.

I have no circular references in the entirety of the solution. I'll admit that I didn't go looking for any documents about upgrading to a newer version of .NET. Since we're basically talking about a run-time library, I didn't expect to see the kinds of havoc that the upgrade would wreak on my project.

Look forward to your update.

In net core you can't build separate executables into the same output folder and share common dependencies/references across such an executables. There is the feature request for this, but it is not planned for implementation yet.
The only option I know to have several executables in the same folder is the following:

build and publish each executable separately into separate location as self-contained (single file)
copy all the executables into the one folder

And even in this case you will have the full set of dependencies packed into the each executable, so all the dependencies will be duplicated multiple times and the final total size of the build artifacts will be significantly larger then with the net 4.8.
As the (non-standard) alternative you can try the NetBeauty and its shared runtimes feature.
Added later to address the comments

but this approach simply seems to be pretty stupid.

Yes! In your use case - it is. It may be that this use case is just out of the scope for the net runtime design team requirements. Or they have gotten some significant benefits by dropping this use case and by using the current approach. Anyway, we have exactly what we have.

it only makes sense to have all the DLLs built into the same
directory, along with all the applications, so that all the references
can easily be resolved.

No, not really. When you use net4.8 and build all your apps in the same directory, you can easily get into a situation, where you have different versions of dependencies (nuget packages, native libs, etc) for the different parts of your build tree. And those dependencies will simply be overwritten in the build directory: you will get the version from the project, that was built last. So, with net4.8 and your build configuration you have no compile-time guarantees that your all apps in the output directory will work. Moreover, you have no guarantee of a stable build: depending on what files were changed, what build optimisations were used during the incremental build, what build order was used and so on, you will get different build results and different problems. And the only way to avoid problems is to manually track all the dependencies (including transitive ones) and make sure that you use the same versions everywhere. It looks pretty much as the classic dll hell.

Having to copy each DLL into the directory holding the application
means I'd end up with an unknown crazy number of copies of the DLLs,
and making it simply too easy to have the wrong copy shipped

With net8 you have an isolated set of dependencies for each executable. There is no way to mix up the versions during the build. The dotnet publish will collect exactly the versions used for the specific part of the build tree.
Moreover, you can use the Centralized Package Management to ensure that you are using the same versions of nuget packages throughout the solution.
So, you can't just get the "wrong copy shipped" because the tooling will automatically track and package all the dependencies (unless you have a custom build logic with just a "copy files manually" approach).
And unlike net4.8, net8 gives you compile-time dependency consistency guarantees for each executable (and global consistency across different executables if you use centralised management).
The only problem is the inability to deduplicate dependencies.

Not to be obsequious, but this approach simply seems to be pretty stupid. I have a library of 9 DLLs that are referenced, in some case, by each other, and 15 application programs that use one or more of those DLLs. Therefore, it only makes sense to have all the DLLs built into the same directory, along with all the applications, so that all the references can easily be resolved. Having to copy each DLL into the directory holding the application means I'd end up with an unknown crazy number of copies of the DLLs, and making it simply too easy to have the wrong copy shipped.

To continue, what about the reference resolution problem? Is each application going to have to have copies of each DLL it uses in order to make sure that all the reference linkage gets resolved correctly? Moving into a structure like that just simply makes no sense.

@npowroz, I updated the answer to address your comments.

Okay, I understand everything you are saying, but from what I saw when I did the upgrade to .NET8, every executable (or DLL) ended up in a different directory, buried somewhat deeply in the hierarchy of the solution. So, if I try to debug one of the executables, how do references to DLLs cross over correctly, so I can see the code flow? Unless all the dependent DLLs have been copied into the EXE's directory, won't the references break? I'm likely going to need to play with this some more, but for now time pressures mean I am probably going to stay in 4.8 for this round of updates.

You should not worry about copying dependencies during the debugging. If you have configured dependencies correctly with the ProjectReference/PackageReference/etc, the just press F5 to debug and have fun. All the dependencies will be automatically harvested through the build tree, copied to the correct location and resolved at runtime. The only problem might be the attempt to run (Process.Start()) the other executable from the current one (because the executables are now built in the separate folders).

Now, to me, that right there is what makes this stupid -- "dependencies will be harvested and copied to the correct location and resolved at runtime". There never used to be any reason to be copying files to various locations just to be able to initiate a debug session. The disjoint structure of the new approach is what requires this.
I need to examine this in a lot greater detail, as I can see that MS isn't making it easy to do what should be a simple upgrade of a runtime library. For now, I'm going to keep my project as is, and then create a test project when I'm not pressed. Thank you.
